# How do I change the scrolling distance of a UIView to be like Safari app

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I want to have a `UIScrollView` that scrolls less then the full screen so that it looks like the Safari app does when you go to make a new tab or look at all the tabs. What property would this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When viewing "tabs" in Mobile Safari each tab is a UIWebView placed in a paged UIScrollView.  When you "zoom out" to switch between them a `CGAffineTransform` to reduce the scale of the web view is being applied.